# Arrow shaped navbar - Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add an arrow to my active navbar but without success.
I am using FA (font awesome) icon in my navbar.
I was trying to use FA right arrow icon and append it to my navbar but without success.
Here is my code:

HTML -

```
<body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-left">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="wishlist.html"><img src="image/logo3.png"></a>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li class="li1"><a href="wishlist.html"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:30px;"></i></a></li>
           <li class="li2"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:30px;"></i></a></li>
           <li class="li3"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:30px;"></i></a></li>
           <li class="li4"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:30px;"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.navbar-brand {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0px;
}

.navbar-brand img {
    height: 60px;
    width: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    margin: -10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.navbar-fixed-left {
    width: 81px;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
}

.navbar-fixed-left .navbar-brand > li {
    float: none;  /* Cancel default li float: left */
    width: 80px;
}

.navbar-fixed-left .navbar-brand > li.active{
    position: relative;
  }
.navbar-fixed-left .navbar-nav > li.active:after{
    border-bottom: 10px solid #e7e7e7;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    content: "rerereree";
    height: 10px;
    left: 40px;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -10px;
    width: 0;
  }
```

Thank you.

*Update - screenshot of what I am trying to get*
This is what I am trying to get.
[image: The result I want to reach.]

New Image!
[image]

Comment: Do you have this in the <head> section?  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

Comment: Is it possible for you to do a fiddle or pen? I attempt to place all your codes in a fiddle with bootstrap loaded by only a small broken image is show with a cut out navbar

Comment: I will a screenshot of what I want to get. And yes @mlegg , I have the folder of FA in my local folders and I've declared in the Header section.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few changes to css made. you were referencing "navbar-brand" instead of "navbar-nav" in the css. therefore it wasn't targeting the right element.

hope this is what you are after: 
https://jsfiddle.net/adx8cu21/3/

```
.navbar {
    border-radius: 0px;
}

.navbar-brand {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0px;
}

.navbar-brand img {
    height: 60px;
    width: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    margin: -10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.navbar-fixed-left {
    width: 81px;
    /*position: fixed;*/
    height: 100%;
}

.navbar-fixed-left .navbar-nav  li {
    float: none;  /* Cancel default li float: left */
    width:80px;
    border: solid 1px green;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0px auto;
    display:table;
    text-align:center;
}

.navbar-fixed-left .navbar-brand > li.active{
    position: relative;

  }
.navbar-fixed-left .navbar-nav > li.active:after{
    border:solid 1px red;
    content: "\f054";
    display:inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    left:130px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:5px;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to insert the right arrow on the right side, like in the screenshot I've added now in the original post.

Comment: no worries, under .navbar-fixed-left .navbar-nav > li.active:after you can update to left:130px;

Comment: @shyamo since the `after` content is positioned absolutely you could probably get away with the `right: 0` rather than `left: 130px;` allowing for expansion of the original container.

Comment: @press if you use 'right:0px;' the right arrow element would be to the right of the container, however the arrow should show outside the container, so you would need to use negative right or use left. see: https://jsfiddle.net/adx8cu21/4/

Comment: @shyamo and Press thank you for the help! I was succeeded to insert the square to my navbar, but now I can't change it to the exact icon, I see always the square instead of the right angle. I have also another issue, after making these changes the background of my icons has changed to black and I can't figure how remove it to be transparent. Attaching screenshot on top.